# Picker in swiftUI is selecting document ID instead of document field from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, uipickerview

So what I am trying to do is use a firebase collection within a picker in a form in swiftui but when I select the sport I want, the document ID of that sport is what gets saved to my variable.

So this is my view where I have the picker.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var sportsObserved = sportsObserver()
    
    @State private var sport = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Form {                
                Picker(selection: $sport, label: Text("Sport")) {
                    ForEach(self.sportsObserved.sports) { i in
                        Text(i.sportName)
                    }
                }
                Text("You selected \(sport)")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

These are the fields of my Firestore document.

```
struct datatype3: Identifiable{
    
    var id : String
    var sportName: String
    var eventCount: Int
}
```

This is my database observable object which wasn't as necessary but I included it just in case someone needed it to fully reproduce the bug I am experiencing.

```
class sportsObserver: ObservableObject{
    @Published var sports = [datatype3]()
    init() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("sports").addSnapshotListener{ (snap, err) in
            
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            for i in snap!.documentChanges{
                
                if i.type == .added {
                    
                    let id = i.document.documentID
                    let sportName = i.document.get("sportName") as! String
                    let eventCount = i.document.get("eventCount") as! Int
                    
                    
                    self.sports.append(datatype3(id: id, sportName: sportName, eventCount: eventCount))
                }
                
                if i.type == .removed {
                  
                     let id = i.document.documentID
                    
                    for j in 0..<self.sports.count{
                        
                        if self.sports[j].id == id{
                            self.sports.remove(at: j)
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if i.type == .modified {
                    let id = i.document.documentID
                    let sportName = i.document.get("sportName") as! String
                    let eventCount = i.document.get("eventCount") as! Int


                    for j in 0..<self.sports.count{

                        if self.sports[j].id == id{
                            self.sports[j].sportName = sportName
                            self.sports[j].eventCount = eventCount

                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result of this is as follows once I chose "Basketball" :[image]

As you can see the document ID of Basketball is set to 12Basketball in my database, this cannot simply be changed to "Basketball" because of other things I have to take into consideration when constructing my database.

What I would like is for the variable "sport" to store "Basketball" which is the sportName and not "12Basketball" which is the documentID.

> This is a fix that I came up with, I would still love if someone could show me a better way as this way is quite clunky.

```
.onAppear {
            for i in sportsObserved.sports {
                if sportID == i.id {
                    sport = i.sportName
                }
            }
```

```
Picker(selection: $sportID, label: Text("Sport")) {
                    ForEach(self.sportsObserved.sports) { i in
                        Text(i.sportName).tag(i.id)
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting the fix as a Community Wiki for visibility:

```
.onAppear {
            for i in sportsObserved.sports {
                if sportID == i.id {
                    sport = i.sportName
                }
            }
```

```
Picker(selection: $sportID, label: Text("Sport")) {
                    ForEach(self.sportsObserved.sports) { i in
                        Text(i.sportName).tag(i.id)
                    }
                }
```